# Javascript supposed to show text if time from to is specific value

Tags: javascript

My javascript code is supposed to show a specific text if the time is inside a specific time space.

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
var myDate = new Date(); 

if ( myDate.getHours() > 0 || myDate.getHours() < 23 || myDate.getMinutes() > 00 || myDate.getMinutes() < 00 || myDate.getDay() == 4  ) )  
{ 
    document.write("ss");
} 
else  /* klokken er ikke imellem 0 og 24 så der er en fejl! */
{ 
    document.write("Jeg er ikke sikker på hvad klokken er!"); 
} 

</script>
```

Comment: What is your question? If this is not working, what output are you getting?

Comment: I want to make a school schedule to show when you have to have maths class and such thing, and its supposed to show it inside of specific time periods.

Comment: Do you realize you are using OR and not AND? If any of those condtions is true, it will be true. And your minute check makes no sense...

Comment: Right now you're displaying "ss" regardless of the time because you're using `||`. What are the real conditions for displaying "ss"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need 00. Just 0. 
You don't need `) )` at the end of OR conditions, just one brace. `)`
You don't need `language` attribute, language attribute is depreciated. Use type instead. `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: All true. Still this is not an answer (since there's no question).

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error on the line of your if condition. You have two right parentheses and you only need one.